# How to use more qualifiers, like Shift, with Appskey (Menu key)

Tags: autohotkey

Using the Windows Menu key (between Right Windows key and Control) on usual keyboards provides a nice qualifier key for defining macros in AutoHotKey. This is called Appskey in AutoHotKey, so e.g. Menu T can send "Hello Menu T" with:

```
Appskey & T::Send Hello Menu T
```

Is there a way to use additional qualifier, like Shift (referenced as +), with Appskey ?

I tried some obvious possibilities without luck, like:

```
Appskey & + T::Send Hello Menu Shift T
+ Appskey & T::Send Hello Menu Shift T
```

However, these fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [#If directive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) to make the combination context-sensitive:

```
Appskey & T::Send Hello Menu T


#If GetKeyState("Shift","P")

    Appskey & T::Send Hello Menu Shift T

#If  ; turn off context sensitivity
```

or this:

```
Appskey & T::
    If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
        Send Hello Menu Shift T
    else
    If GetKeyState("Ctrl","P")
        Send Hello Menu Ctrl T
    else
        Send Hello Menu T
return
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the 2nd method best... Though not as pretty as the oneliner that the usual "+" can do for Shift...  I will let the question open for a couple of days to see if there is a nicer solution, and otherwise accept your answer :-)

Comment: Combinations of three or more keys are not supported. See https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo

Comment: It still works for me; thanks for the help, and answer accepted :-)